# chown + chmod 700, still cant paste files in /opt/lampp/htdocs

Tags: 14.04, permissions, php, lamp

This seems basic & easy, but man...i got headache here.

I followed this question : [How to save php file in /opt/lampp/htdocs without going to terminal and type sudo gedit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55312/how-to-save-php-file-in-opt-lampp-htdocs-without-going-to-terminal-and-type-sud)

I want to be able to do copy-paste to the /opt/lampp/htdocs. This is what i did on terminal :

1. See current user & group : users -> result : tama tama
2. `sudo chown tama:tama /opt/lampp/htdocs`
3. `sudo chmod 700 /opt/lampp/htdocs`

The owner of the files has changed successfully, but i still cant do paste there. (greyed out)

Result of `stat  /opt/lampp/htdocs` :

```
  File: ‘/opt/lampp/htdocs’
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 805h/2053d  Inode: 5505136     Links: 11
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: ( 1000/    tama)   Gid: ( 1000/    tama)
Access: 2014-11-07 13:51:31.488418404 +0700
Modify: 2014-01-27 17:37:56.969253666 +0700
Change: 2014-11-07 13:50:37.232417525 +0700
 Birth: -
```

Result of `ls -l  /opt/lampp/htdocs` :

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 tama   tama    4096 Nov 13  2013 alif
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root   root    1444 Jun 10  2013 applications.html
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root   root    2142 Apr 29  2013 bitnami.css
drwxrwxr-x 6 tama   tama    4096 Jan 27  2014 bluezsteak
drwxrwxr-x 4 tama   tama    4096 Nov 11  2013 budi
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root   root   30894 Mei 11  2007 favicon.ico
drwxrwxr-x 8 tama   tama    4096 Okt  1  2013 gabdb
drwxrwxr-x 2 root   root    4096 Okt  9  2013 img
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root   root     256 Peb  6  2009 index.php
drwxrwxr-x 4 tama   tama    4096 Nov 14  2013 jewelry
drwxrwxr-x 8 tama   tama    4096 Okt 13  2013 kmbd
drwxrwxr-x 2 daemon daemon  4096 Okt  9  2013 webalizer
drwxrwxr-x 7 root   root    4096 Okt  9  2013 xampp
```

Please kindly help me. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @muru done :)  Please see my edited question

Comment: The files are all still owned by root, and  some of the directories aren't owned by `tama` either, so perhaps you're trying to paste in one of those? Can you do it using the terminal? `cp some-file /opt/lampp/htdocs`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try recursively `chown`
`sudo chown -R tama:tama /opt/lampp/htdocs`

Comment: Thanks. No luck, do i need to do -R for 700 also? Is it dangerous?

Comment: I'd recommend setting chmod to 644 but 755 also works

Comment: just use -R 700 and its working. Thanks a lot