# How can I save /var/www/html

Tags: permissions

Lamp is installed on my home machine and will never be for public viewing. I'm learning to program.

When I code in Notepadqq and try to save the file `var/www/html/` I get `permission denied`. So, I used this command in terminal:

```
sudo chmod 766 -R /var/www/html
```

In the example I was copying, this command was given:

```
sudo chown pi /var/www/html
```

I got this from terminal in response.

```
chown: invalid user: ‘pi’
```

I then realised pi was not my name, so I then tried

```
sudo chown Bobby /var/www/html
```

as Bobby is my name. But I still got

```
chown: invalid user: ‘Bobby’
```

So I tried this

```
sudo chmod 766 -r /var/www/html
```

as per the example. But I got

```
chmod: cannot access '766': No such file or directory
```

Eish.

All I would like to do is to be able save the programming I am learning in that file so I can load it through the apache server which is up and running.

Help please

Comment: The last error seems unlikely. Are you sure you ran exactly that command? Your username is probably all lowercase - look at your prompt in the terminal - your username will probably appear at the beginning before the `@` symbol. You can also type `whoami` to see your username. `echo $USER` should also work. Be careful with `chown` and `chmod` as you can trash your system pretty comprehensively with a minor typo when using them. Also be aware that directories need execute permission to be entered, and giving write permission to "others" is a security risk, so 766 is not generally a useful mode

Answer (score 0):

You can run the file manager in super user mode by the following command in terminal `gksudo nautilus`

or please follow instruction from here.
https://askubuntu.com/a/55365/546041

Thank You